# How to copy .xml files from a known directory with a variable folder name?

Tags: batch-file

I need to move `.xml` files to known destination, but the thing is that I don't know the name of the parent folder that I want to move it from because the name is being created randomly.

```
Sourcefolder                                     DestinationFolder
|    |StaticFolder                                  |
|        | AnotherStaticFolder                          |
|           | RandomFolder(YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS)            | /.xml
|               | StaticFolder
|                 /.xml
```

How can I do it this with robocopy or any batch command?

The random name is created by an app which creates the folder name as format `YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS`.

Comment: Are there more than one `YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS` folder? If yes, how to decide which one to choose? The latest?

Comment: Generally, there is just one such folder...but if there are more, I need to copy files from a particular subFolder of all these random folders.
Eg. C:\PgmFiles\Test\YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS-1\Logs\*xml                                                
      C:\PgmFiles\Test\YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS-2\Logs\*xml        .....Then I need all the .xmls from both the Logs folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply recursively search for any xml file in a specific directory structure.

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\SourceFolder" %%i in (*.xml) do copy "%%i" "C:\DestinationFolder"
```

See `for /?` from `cmd.exe` for more help on the command

**Edit**

As per your comment, though still unclear, it seems that you get a new date directory created often, so we can sort the directories by date (newest last) then simply copy the xml from the latest:

```
@echo off
pushd "C\Program Files\Tests"
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad /od') do set "mypath=%%~dpfi"
copy "%mypath%\Current\Logsxml\*.xml" "C:\DestinationFolder"
```

**NOTE** this is assuming you have a directory as per your comment called, `logsxml` if it is just called `logs` containing `xml` files then simply change the last line to:

```
copy "%mypath%\Current\Logs\*.xml" "C:\DestinationFolder"
```

To copy all the xml files from the date directories, do:

```
@echo off
pushd "C\Program Files\Tests"
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad /od') do (
copy /Y "%%i\Current\Logsxml\*.xml" "C:\DestinationFolder"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it copies all .xml files of the folder whereas I need files from a particular folder inside the subdirectory. To be specific, the source is "C\Program Files\Tests\2019_01_22_16_27_08\Current\Logs\*xml" where 2019_01_22_16_27_08 keeps changing and there are various other folders and .xml in the "Current" folder. How to handle this?

Comment: Oh great, it worked! :D Thanks a lot for a prompt reply. I regret for such unclear explanation.

Comment: @SwatiSingh cool. If you feel any of the answers here helped you solve your problem, please consider selecting it as the correct answer by ticking the grey tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: Also, what to do if I need to copy .xmls from all these date directories and not just the latest?

Comment: Also, how to delete the already existing content before coping?

Comment: No, now you are pushing a single question to the limit, you would need to create a new question :)

Comment: oh ok :P found the answer on another question posted already :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop over the `dir` command (which allows wildcards) like so:

```
SET dest=dest_directory
SET source=\Tests\\.*\\Current\\Logs\\.*\.xml$
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('dir * /s/b ^| findstr %source%') DO (
    xcopy %%g %dest%
)
```

`dest` is the DestinationFolder
`source` is a regex that matches the path of your xml files. (Note that you have to escape file separators `\` in the path and the `.` in the file extension with `\`. Hence the double `\\` and `\.xml`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it copies the .xml files to correct dest. from the folder where this batch script is pasted. when I do not change anything in ('dir /s/b *.xml'). As I am new to this batch scripting, I do not really understand how to use StaticFolder\*.xml here. Here, the source is "C\Program Files\Tests\2019_01_22_16_27_08\Current\Logs*xml" where 2019_01_22_16_27_08 keeps changing and there are various other folders and .xml in the "Current" folder. How to handle this?

Comment: See my edits. I modified the script so you can use a regex to match your XML files. Your regex should be something like `\C:\\Program Files\\Tests\\.*\\Current\\Logsxml\\.*\.xml$`.